# Adjusting for ARCH effect in regression analysis

Tags: regression, arima, least-squares, econometrics, garch

I have the following regression: yt = b0 + b1X1t + b2X2t + b3X3t + e

I then saw that e is serially correlated so I modeled the regression with ARIMA errors. However, then I saw that there was an ARCH effect present.

I now would like to account for the ARCH effect.

What I would usually do is, save the residual of the autocorrelation-fixed regression; square them (the residuals) and model them (the residuals) with ARIMA model that makes the error iid(0,v). Once I have that I will take the fitted values of that model (lets call it h) and then take the square root of that (lets call it sqrt_h).

I would then divide my original variables with sqrt_h and would expect the ARCH effect to be accounted for.

However, I did that and it seems to not be working for my current model.

Can you recommend any other way of accounting for ARCH effect in your regression. My aim is to interpret the regression so I need a correct model.

Comment: You could estimate a joint model accounting for all these features at once, then you would get correct (or perhaps less incorrect) standard errors. For example, in R you could use package `rugarch` with the main variables as `external.regressors` in the `mean.model` in function `ugarchspec`.

Comment: Ah, I know that you can estimate both equations with maximum likelihood but I was trying to avoid that for some reason.

Because in my mind as the ARCH effect is literature et = lo + l1e^2t-1 + .. + lpe^2t-p (AR(p) of the squared error).

So dividing the original variables by the AR(p) fitted values of the square error would cancel out the ARCH effect (at least theoretically in the mathematics).

I will check the packages you suggested :) Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You should not be dividing the original variables but the model residuals, because it is the residuals that are conditionally heteroskedastic as modelled by GARCH or something like it in its place.

Comment: Yes, but by dividing the variables with the "ARCH" effect it will cancel out in the error.
y / sqrt_h = b0 / sqrt_h + b1x1 / sqrt_h + e, where e is iid(0,1) and this 1 is a constant coming from the divisition.

Comment: Fine, but you will at the same time introduce side effects for the remaining part of the variable (i.e. the observed value minus the error). Actually, dividing anything by the fitted conditional variance might not be a good idea in the first place; weighting inversely proportionately to it might be a better one. This would yield more efficient estimates (WLS more efficient than OLS).